# The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

#### Versions

- nuxt: ^2.14.12
- node: v14.15.4

#### Reproduction

Hello everyone and thank you in advance.
I have a strange issue that I don't really understand what's the problem and how to deal with it.
I have installed a fresh nuxt ssr project.
I'm getting the following warning
`[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

I have three simple components: `Form`, `Input`, `Button`.
`Form.vue`

```js
<template>
  <form v-bind="$attrs" class="w-full" @submit.prevent="$emit('submitted')">
    <div class="space-y-2 mb-4">
      <slot name="fields" />
    </div>
      <slot name="button" />
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    hasFields() {
      return !!this.$slots.fields
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`Input.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="relative w-full">
    <input class="form-input block w-full" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

`Button.vue`

```js
<template>
  <button
    type="submit"
    class="relative btn inline-flex items-center justify-center transition ease-in-out duration-150"
  >
    Save
  </button>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

I use my components in `pages/index.vue` like this:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Form>
      <template #fields>
        <Input />
        <Input />
      </template>
      <template #button>
        <Button />
      </template>
    </Form>
    <Form>
      <template #fields>
        <Input />
        <Input />
      </template>
      <template #button>
        <Button />
      </template>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

If i use the `Form` component only once in the view i don't get the warning.
If i use it twice i get it.

#### Steps to reproduce

[Reproduction link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-mcclintock-swx70?file=/pages/index.vue)

1. Install a fresh nuxt ssr project.
2. Create the components as in the reproduction link

#### What is Expected?

All the components to render normally without any warnings or errors.

#### What is actually happening?

I get the following warning.
`[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

**Some extra notes**

1. I know that wrapping the whole thing inside a `<client-only>` fixes the problem but i want to understand why is this happening in order to avoid it in future cases.
2. Also if I remove `components: true` from `nuxt.config.js` and import the components normally again the warning is gone.
3. Changing the name of the components eg `Button` -> `TheButton` won't fix the problem. You can see the [reproduction here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-neumann-6h3ju?file=/pages/index.vue).

```js
<script>
import Input from '~/components/Input'
import Button from '~/components/Button'
import Form from '~/components/Form'

export default {
  components: { Form, Button, Input}
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think there seems to be one or more components which are not supported in "Universal" mode. You'll just need to find that component maybe by trial and error method and wrap the same with the tag <client-only>. Here's the link for the same: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be one or more components which are not supported in "Universal" Mode, i.e. they might have code which isn't being executed correctly on server end.

Please try finding that component which you think can cause an issue and wrap that component with .

Here's the link for more information: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component